# Can't override onRequestPermissionResult in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio, interface, overriding, android-permissions

I found the code below in this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)(-> Android Developer Guide). I copied the code and did some minor changes like picking the permission needed for my Application. The issue here is that I can't override `onRequestPermissionResult` as shown in the tutorial. Whenever I try to, the IDE states `Method does not override method from its superclass`.

Superclass?? As shown in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback) the method `onRequestPermissionResult` is part of the interface `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`. Therefore I tried implementing the interface and the did the following change: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`.

This didn't solve the problem ...

```
package com.example.test1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements  ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission not granted");

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)){
                Log.d(TAG, "some explanation is required??? wut");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "requests permission");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionResult (int requestCode,
                                          String[] permissions,
                                          int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission was granted");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission was denied");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `onRequestPermissionsResult`. Note the **s** in Permission**s**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Michael - Thanks for this, I was going in circles for 20 minutes, had the same problem, simply because I've copied & pasted the code from Android documentation.

The typo is in the documentation so if you copy & paste the code from there. you will end up with this. :)